# NPM Install "Cannot Find Module ' node-darwin-arm64/package.json' on M1 Chip

Tags: node.js, npm

I know different versions of this question have been asked, but I've yet to see a solution that doesn't involve installing with rosetta or faking the architecture with zsh. I use bash and would like to not deal with Rosetta where possible.

I'm a node newbie and am struggling to figure out what's even failing.

Node - v16.14.0

NPM - 8.3.1

Yarn - 1.22.17

I get the same errors with npm or yarn.

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/joefedorowicz/Development/xwingui/react-ui/node_modules/node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node installArchSpecificPackage
npm ERR! npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for node-darwin-arm64@12.22.6.
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     /Users/joefedorowicz/.npm/_logs/2022-02-16T15_52_10_981Z-debug.log
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'node-darwin-arm64/package.json'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - /Users/joefedorowicz/Development/xwingui/react-ui/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/xwingui/react-ui/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:18:27)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:520:28)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5) {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: [
npm ERR!     '/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/xwingui/react-ui/node_modules/node/installArchSpecificPackage.js'
npm ERR!   ]
npm ERR! }
```

Answer (score 23):

Reinstalling node with this arch flag worked for me:

```
$ nvm uninstall 14
$ arch -x86_64 zsh 
$ nvm install 14
$ nvm alias default 14
```

As per [this](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv/issues/560#issuecomment-1029392300) post.

Comment: This solution worked for me as well. I have a Mac M1 Pro, had the same issue when running yarn install